# Can't install Windows 7 from USB

Tags: windows, bios, installation

Computer:

```
Samsung 350v5c-s04
windows 8 (64bit)
CPU: i5 3210m
HDD: 1 TB (5.4kr sata)
```

As you can see, there was Windows 8 installed.

I created bootable Windows 7 USB and tried to install it. After 2 hour finally I reached point where I can install.

I removed all partitions and tried to install new version. Everything seems to be good, but on "finalizing installation" my pc rebooted and I got again windows 7 installation menu. I changed some BIOS settings (was trying to load HDD with windows), but this happened.

When I turn on the PC, the  "Samsung" image loads and then I get black screen and nothing happens. Can't boot from my USB flash drive either. I changed BIOS many times without any results.

After I turn on the PC:

[image]

After 2s I get this:

[image]

My BIOS settings.

[image: BIOS settings: Sysinfo and advanced]

[image: BIOS settings: Boot]

[image]

I can not start from USB anymore. I dunno why. On other computers the USB pendrive boots properly. I want to install windows 7.

Comment: Wich tool did you use to create a the usb bootable win7?....you need to disable the Fast Boo option....let me try an asnwer XD

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First:

- Choose a proper tool to make the usb bootable, like:

[Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe)

Or

[Bootable USB](http://www.deviantart.com/download/155238367/A_Bootable_USB_by_Vishal_Gupta.zip)

[WinToBootic](http://www.wintobootic.com/release/WiNToBootic_v2.1.zip)

Second:

- You need to disable the Fast Boot option in the BIOS

An Third:

- You may then find that pressing F10 at the BIOS screen gives you a one-time boot device list

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the BIOS settings and go to the Boot list. Change USB to the first one, then restart. If you did it right, and your PC isn't plain broke from partition failures, hard drive sector issues, or anything really, then you should get install menu. After it restarts, don't let it do anything. Go back to the BIOS. Then change boot order to HDD/SDD first.